# How can I accept or delete any pending post?

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic-data

I am very very disappointed this time. I wasted my whole day and I couldn't help me out. Here is the problem:

I need accept or delete the pending jobs. If I accept, only then it will publish on my site. Please look at the image.[image]

Here I am trying this code to handle this matter. Firstly if anyone post a new job, I pass a hidden value=0 according to the job.

```
<input type="hidden" name="pending" value=0/>
```

Then I store it in my database.

```
INSERT INTO job (Pending) VALUES ('$_POST[pending]');
```

Then I go to the image(above) page to accept or delete.

```
echo "<a href='accept.php?accept=1'>ACCEPT</a> Or ";
echo "<a href='accept.php?accept=0'>DELETE</a>";
```

After accepting Pending column will be replaced from 0 to 1 and thus it will be published. Or deleting time, the job will be simply be deleted from database.

```
$accept=$_GET['accept'];
if($accept==1){
mysql_query("UPDATE job SET Pending='$accept'
WHERE ID='5'");
}
else{
mysql_query("DELETE FROM job WHERE ID='5'");
}
```

In the 'job' table, I use a primary auto increment column named ID. I put 5 for ID. So this code will work only for the pending job which ID is 5. So my problem is here. How can I alternate this 5 with a dynamic variable?

FOR MORE ASSISTANCE HERE IS the CODE OF 'PENDING JOBS' PAGE;

```
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM job ORDER BY ID DESC");
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
{
 $id=$row1['ID'];
 $cat=$row1['Category'];
 $title=$row1['Title'];
 $type=$row1['Type'];
 $desp=$row1['Description'];
 $salary=$row1['Salary'];
 $day=$row1['Day'];
 $month=$row1['Month'];
 $year=$row1['Year'];
 $info=$row1['Contact'];
 $pending=$row1['Pending'];

 $now = time();
 $last_date = strtotime("$year-$month-$day");
 $datediff = $last_date - $now;
 $day_left=ceil($datediff/(60*60*24));
 if($day_left>=0&&$pending==0){
echo "<div class=cat>Job field: $cat<br/></div>";
  echo "<div class=yel2>";
 echo "This is a <b>$type time</b> job and we are looking for <b>$title</b>. $desp<br/>";
if ($salary!=0) echo "Salary: $salary<br/>";
echo "Contact info: $info<br/>Last date: $day-$month-$year";
 if($day_left==0)
 echo "<br/><span class=ash><i>Today is the last day to apply</i><br/>";
else
 echo "<br/><span class=ash><i>$day_left day(s) left</i></span><br/>";
 echo "<span class=acc><a href='accept.php?accept=1'>ACCEPT</a><span> Or ";
 echo "<span class=del><a href='accept.php?accept=0'>DELETE</a></span>";
```

Comment: why you are not storing and reading in a div $id ??

Comment: Just pass the id as a url variable to the accept page?

Comment: **WARNING!** Your code contains an [SQL injection vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) -- you are passing raw, unfiltered, unvalidated user input directly into an SQL string. SQL injection is [very easy to fix](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/168868). Consider [switching to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli) so you can use [prepared statements with parameterized queries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass the id along with the accept url.

```
echo "<span class=acc><a href='accept.php?id=$id&accept=1'>ACCEPT</a><span> Or ";
```

You can grab the id inside the accept.php script using

```
$post_id = $_GET['id'];
```

The code would require little change

```
$accept = intval($_GET['accept']); // safe against sql-injections
$post_id = intval($_GET['id']);
if($accept==1){
mysql_query("UPDATE job SET Pending='$accept'
WHERE ID='$post_id'");
}
else{
mysql_query("DELETE FROM job WHERE ID='$post_id'");
}
```

Comment: Wow great solution. I am going to try this. I will let you know if I succeed.

Comment: I am very very grateful to you. You are such a helpful person Michael. :)